# The quad function in scipy.integrate displays the absolute error of the integration, how do I disable that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

```
    def mofp(p,mu,Z):
        return 2*p/(mu*Z)
    mp=()
    for p_bar in pwf:
        m_p= quad(mofp,p_bar,pres,args=(mu,Z))
        mp=mp+m_p
    print(mp)
```

It displays the integration value along with the error of integration that I do not want

Output:

> (0.0, 0.0, 11422187.902904231, 1.268117600139921e-07,
>   22731910.472957242, 2.5237490400794864e-07, 33929167.71015946, 3.766894319818743e-07, 45013959.614510655, 4.997553439357666e-07, 55986286.18601066, 6.215726398696237e-07, 66846147.42465983,.....)

Comment: The line `mp=mp+m_p` is not performing addition, it is concatenating tuples. Using @Warren's solution solves this problem.

Comment: @DaveP  `mp` is initialized as an empty tuple, so my suggestion will cause a problem.  Nitya, are you trying to sum up all the values, or are you intentionally saving all the individual values in a tuple?

Answer (score 2):

[`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a tuple containing two values.  You can't disable that, but you can ignore the second value by indexing the result to use just the first value:

```
        m_p = quad(mofp, p_bar, pres, args=(mu, Z))[0]
```

An alternative is to unpack the values in the assignment:

```
        m_p, abserr = quad(mofp, p_bar, pres, args=(mu, Z))
```

Then you have `abserr` available if you decide you want to inspect the error estimate.

I assume you want to add up all these values, not store them in a tuple, so you'll also need to change the initialization of `mp` from `mp=()` to `mp = 0`.

---

If, in fact, you want to save all the separate `quad` results, I suggest using something like

```
mp = []
for p_bar in pwf:
    m_p = quad(mofp, p_bar, pres, args=(mu, Z))[0]
    mp.append(m_p)
```

or more concisely, with a list comprehension:

```
mp = [quad(mofp, p_bar, pres, args=(mu, Z))[0] for p_bar in pwf]
```

Comment: For this solution to work, you need to replace `mp=()` with `mp=0`.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the correct change, unless the goal is to save all the individual calculations in a tuple (or some other sequence).  Awaiting clarification...

Comment: works perfectly using the index [0], thanks a lot Warren.